# Checking state of checkbutton from dynamic list

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a list of checkbuttons that I generate based on a query - it populates based on the search criteria and is able to be destroyed through a second search and/or clearing of the list. I also store the checkbutton values in a list (todoList). Where I am struggling is how do I check if the checkbuttons are selected or not in a "submit" function. Below is the way that the checkbuttons are generated w/ the todoList action included. I'm definitely missing something in my logic where I can get the values dynamically but I'm not seeing it and need a little help.

```
  while data:
    specno = data[0]
    fname = data[1]
    lname = data[2]
    self.todoList.append(specno)
    #self.var1 = IntVar()
    n = len(self.buttonList)
    lx = Checkbutton(self.listFrame,
                     text=self.todoList[n],
                     variable=self.todoList[n],
                     onvalue = 1,
                     offvalue = 0)
    ni = n
    self.buttonListNum.append(ni)
    lx.grid(row=n, column=0, sticky='NW')
    self.buttonList.append(lx)
    data = cursor.fetchone()
```

Comment: `variable=` expects `StringVar()`, `IntVar()`, etc. Whn you check checkbutton then it change value in `StringVar()`/`IntVar()`. So you can check this `StringVar()`/`IntVar()`.

Comment: I guess that's where I'm failing - if I were to change the statement to say variable = IntVar() - how do I check that value for all checkbuttons later on?

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out how to deal with this - since state checking requires the variable attribute of checkbutton to be an IntVar(), StrVar(), etc., what I did was set a variable to IntVar() and then append those to a separate list with the same index as my buttonList[] and todoList[] lists so that I can check the state later with the function checkStatus shown below.

```
def add(self):
  self.removeCheckButton()
  entry = self.entryBox.get()
  self.entryBox.delete(0, END)
  search = ("%QUERY%")
  cursor.execute(search)
  data = cursor.fetchone()
  while data:
    specno = data[0]
    fname = data[1]
    lname = data[2]
    self.todoList.append(specno)
    var = IntVar()
    n = len(self.buttonList)
    lx = Checkbutton(self.listFrame,
                     text=self.todoList[n],
                     variable= selvar,
                     onvalue = 1,
                     offvalue = 0)
    ni = n
    self.buttonListNum.append(ni)
    self.varList.append(var)
    lx.grid(row=n, column=0, sticky='NW')
    self.buttonList.append(lx)
    data = cursor.fetchone()


def checkStatus(self):
  for i in self.buttonListNum:
    print(self.varList[i].get())
```

Comment: `buttonListNum` is useless - you can do `for x in self.varList: print(x.get())` And If you need its index then use `enumerate` - `for i, x in enumerate(self.varList): print(i, x.get())`

Answer (score 0):

Your code but cleaner

- you can use `for` instead of `while` and then you don't need `data = cursor.fetchone()`
- you don't need `self.buttonListNum`
- you don't have to add `List` in names. `buttons` and `vars` are more readable. If you want `List` in names then prefered are `button_list` and `var_list`

.

```
for n, data in enumerate(cursor):
    specno = data[0]
    var = IntVar()

    lx = Checkbutton(self.listFrame,
                     text=specno,
                     variable=var,
                     onvalue=1,
                     offvalue=0)
    lx.grid(row=n, column=0, sticky='NW')

    self.todoList.append(specno)
    self.buttons.append(lx)
    self.vars.append(var)
```

and to check vars:

```
def check_status(self):
    for i, var in enumerate(self.vars):
        print(i, var.get())
```

Comment: I do actually need the buttonListNum for a different function that I have not shown, but it is irrelevant to the question here, so you're correct - I should have removed that from my example code. Thank you for your help!

Comment: as for me `buttonListNum` is useless - it has values `[0,1, 2, 3, .. , n-1]`.  You can get the same values with `list(range(n))` where `n = len(buttonList)`  or `n = len(vars)` . But mostly we use `enumerate(some_list)` to get this values.